# Why run print before Dialog.run() is over

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

Okay I edit my question, try to explain it more clearly:

I have a Main Window with on button (addButton), If I click on it, it is show AddDialog with two buttons (ok_btn, cancel_btn), a label (errorLabel) and an entry. Please see the code:

Code link: http://pastebin.com/ketGWctN

Why print the message after AddDialog.run() if I click the btn_ok but the entry doesn't filled?

Comment: Nobody knows the answer?

Comment: Can you explain your question more clearly?

Comment: I try it and hope it is okay now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dialog.run()` runs a loop until the dialog is closed or one of the buttons at the bottom is clicked. So when you click OK, the loop exits and the `Dialog.run()` function returns.

Try disabling the OK button if the entry is not filled.